# Cannot compile MEGA api

Tags: c++, api, msys2

I'm using Windows 7 64bits and been trying to compile the MEGA api with MSYS2 using the autotools, but after running 'make' compilation stops showing this error:

```
# make
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory '/d/sdk-develop'
Making all in include
make[2]: Entering directory '/d/sdk-develop/include'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/d/sdk-develop/include'
make[2]: Entering directory '/d/sdk-develop'
  CXX      examples/megacli-megacli.o
In file included from D:/msys64/mingw64/include/zconf.h:475,
                 from D:/msys64/mingw64/include/zlib.h:34,
                 from ./include/mega/win32/meganet.h:26,
                 from ./include/mega.h:76,
                 from examples/megacli.cpp:22:
./include/mega/win32/megafs.h:170:10: error: 'bool mega::WinFileAccess::ftruncate64()' marked 'override', but does not override
  170 |     bool ftruncate() override;
      |          ^~~~~~~~~
make[2]: *** [Makefile:2742: examples/megacli-megacli.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/d/sdk-develop'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:3294: all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/d/sdk-develop'
make: *** [Makefile:1495: all] Error 2
```

Comment: Compiler message is pretty explicit. When you inspect the code in question do you concur?

Comment: I looked at megafs.h and indeed it says 'override' but I don't know how to fix this

Comment: Make sure the function prototype matches the `ftruncate64` defined by `WinFileAccess`'s base class exactly.. If that also looks correct your best option will probably be to get in touch with the MEGA developers and ask them for advice..

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question should be addressed to the project owners of MEGA.

Comment: In megafs.h I couldn't find any definition of ftruncate64, just found 'bool ftruncate() override;'

Comment: The class definition of `WinFileAccess` should tell you what its base classes are (and if there aren't any, there's the problem) one you know the base classes, looking in the headers included by megafs.h and maybe a bit of `grep`ing should help you track down the base class definition. In the base class